# Diagnosing cascaded routers

Tags: networking, router, firewall

I am running a network containing two routers. The Zyxel P-600 is connected
to the DSL line. I attached the Ethernet port of the Zyxel to
the WAN port of the second router, a D-Link 605L.

Both routers have NAT and a firewall activated and are running a DHCP server.

My devices are all connected to the D-Link router and can reach the internet.
Sometimes it seems it takes a little too long until a connection is established. From time to time ping shows packet losses but the packet loss
is gone if I run ping a second time.

I found no arguments that one MUST run the second router in bridge mode, although this is often claimed. From my basic understanding of NAT
the setup should work at least in theory (and it does).

Another point what is worrying me is that the D-Link router logs
attacks from Internet IPs as well as from the IP of the Zyxel router:

> Per-source ACK Flood Attack Detect
>
> Whole System ACK Flood Attack from WAN Rule:Default deny

As the Zyxel router has a Firewall, these packages should never reach the second D-Link router. This is one of the reasons I do not trust the Zyxel
firewall completely and like to have the additional D-Link one.

What are first steps to diagnose the delay and the occasional package loss?
How can I find out whether the attacks on the D-Link router are actual attacks or just caused by packages which are not routed properly?

Edit: The Zyxel router does not show up as a step in traceroute. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you run the edge router in bridged mode, not the other way around or easier, just use the switch ports if applicable.

You're having latency? Now you know one reason why it's not recommended to cascade routers. You mention it's for security reasons. You're not really gaining security here in general. Not knowing your configurations, it's impossible to do more than speculate how that is a security benefit.

There are many reasons not to cascade routers.

1. If you open a port on the edge router, the other router also needs a port open for devices behind this router.
2. What DNS server is assigned to each router? Are they the same or different? If it takes awhile to get connected to a target, then it could be waiting on a DNS response.
3. Does each router support the services you need for your devices? Ex. VoIP? QoS?

Why would you put a router behind a router? You already had it and/or the 2nd router offers wireless which the first one does not. In your case your primary router is also your telco device for your DSL. That's fine but you can still put it in bridged mode, which allows all public addressing to touch the WAN side of your second router. Then you have the better security you wanted and you only have to deal with single task configurations, not to mention you might just clear up your latency. There's not enough information to be sure.

Edit-
I don't have enough points to comment.

"What are first steps to diagnose the delay and the occasional package loss?"

How are you determining delay? Your setup will introduce unnecessary delays. While ping is not a tool for performance, it can provide limited information about intermittent latency. To find out where, you'll need to do a trace route. You can perform a speed test but that's aggregated performance.

Can you expand on the occasional "package" [packet?] loss? When does this happen? When trying to connect to a target or during a video stream, etc.?

"How can I find out whether the attacks on the D-Link router are actual attacks or just caused by packages which are not routed properly?"

Unless the router is known for issuing false positives, you provided the answer in these two statements and also in the title "cascaded routers."

"The Zyxel P-600 is connected to the DSL line. I attached the Ethernet port of the Zyxel to the WAN port of the second router, a D-Link 605L."

"Another point what is worrying me is that the D-Link router logs attacks from Internet IPs as well as from the IP of the Zyxel router:"

I'll explain. Routers connect dissimilar networks. They only know their neighbors. Your first Zyxel is your D-Link's only neighbor. You're seeing these attacks with the Zyxel's LAN IP because all Internet traffic comes from there. If you have ports open on the Zyxel, you'll see routed traffic from public IP addresses.

Comment: I was expecting latency to go up by maybe 4 ms. Now I have occasional spikes of up to a full second. And I still don't see a REASON for not cascading routers. I only see that I does not work well in my setup.

Comment: NAT modifies source IP on outgoing packets and destination IP on incoming packages. So I should never receive incoming packages from the Internet with Zyxel IP.

Comment: When you say ports open, you mean port forwarding? I don't forward any ports.

Comment: Putting the Zyxel in bridge mode is a good idea. I'll consider that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect packet loss, use something like MTR (or WinMTR).

You can indeed NAT stuff twice - its not best practice, but it mostly works.  It may stuff up some things like p2p and some VOIP applications though (although single NAT can do that as well)

If you configure the second "soho" (toy) router as a bridge, you may as well get a switch.

To determine actual attacks you will need a decent router. (Maybe you can run DD-WR on your D-Link router, and then use ethereal or tcpdump to look at the traffic, depending on the version)